# Insert a background Image in a Hippocms project

Tags: html, css, freemarker, hippocms

I am new to Hippo and I am learning hippo. I opened the folders responsible for the web files. There are four types of folders. CSS, Freemarker, JS and Fonts. I want to make possible that the first page of the site to have a background image. I tried to write in the CSS bootstrap folder the following line, but still does not work.

```
body {
background-image: url("hst.link path='/images/essentials/catalog-component-
icons/banner.png");
background-color: #cccccc;
margin: 0;}
```

Comment: What happens if you just type `url("/images/essentials/catalog-component-
icons/banner.png");`?
Your code doesn't look right with all the params and even a missing quote.

Comment: @Calaris I tried the same way you said, It doesn't work.
This is the code:

    body {
    background-image: url("/images/essentials/catalog-component- 
    icons/banner.png");
    background-color: #cccccc;
    margin: 0;
    }

Comment: It is possible, that your background is being covered with several divs that have non-transparent background-colors, making you image invisible.
You should check this with firebug or other developer tools.